# Product import hangs

Tags: import, csv

I'm trying to import more than 1000 products.
And import takes like 10s or less and hangs, imports like 10 products.. checked system.log only found warnings like  ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: _media_lable
Tried to increase memory limit but no luck as well..
Anyone know the solution? Any information would be very helpful.

Comment: Why not import by magmi?
Its better for this things.

Comment: If there are any errors on the import screen, make sure all the required column headers are there. You can do this by first exporting some of your products (Dataflow profiles, export all products) and then using those headers for importing new products

Comment: I'm using default magento import. Nope there are no errors in the screen, jus one dublicate SKU, but as i assume that it skips it.

Comment: Could you paste your import file? This will probably help resolving the problem.